# Sequential Network Requests in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, cksubscription

I have multiple network requests that need to happen in sequential order. They must wait until the previous has finished and received its response from the server.

Right now I have a callback pyramid of death. Is there a more automated way of doing this? I tried an `OperationQueue` but it doesn't wait for the requests to finish before advancing to the next request even with it set to do one request at a time.

For what it's worth, `.save` is a network request to CloudKit. There is no CloudKit subscription queue like there is with other CloudKit operations.

```
self.privateDB.save(subscriptions[0]){ savedSubscription, error in
  //Request 1 is done
  self.privateDB.save(subscriptions[1]){ savedSubscription, error in
    //Request 2 is done
    self.privateDB.save(subscriptions[2]){ savedSubscription, error in
      //All 3 requests are done
    }
  }
}
```

I tried a `DispatchGroup` but this doesn't seem to work. All the requests seem to fire before waiting for a response.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

//Create a subscription for every record type
for subscription in subscriptions{
  group.enter()
  //...
  self.privateDB.save(subscription){ savedSubscription, error in
    group.leave()
  }    
}
group.wait()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create one or more `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` to save the subscriptions, then use `CKDatabase.add()` to run them. If you need them to run in order, set up dependencies between them to ensure they run in order:

```
let subscriptionOp1 = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: subscriptions[0], subscriptionsToDelete: nil)
let subscriptionOp2 = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: subscriptions[1], subscriptionsToDelete: nil)
let subscriptionOp3 = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: subscriptions[2], subscriptionsToDelete: nil)

subscriptionOp2.addDependency(subscriptionOp1)
subscriptionOp3.addDependency(subscriptionOp2)

database.add(subscriptionOp1)
database.add(subscriptionOp2)
database.add(subscriptionOp3)
```

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation`. That's exactly what I need here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use semaphore to make them in sync.

1. Create semaphore

   var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
2. wait for completion of 1st api call

   dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
3. Signal the semaphore in 1st api completion.

   dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)

Ex :

var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    self.privateDB.save(subscriptions[0]){ savedSubscription, error in
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    self.privateDB.save(subscriptions[1]){ savedSubscription, error in}